# How to make CMYK Spectrum the same in two documents in Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk

I have two documents open in Adobe Illustrator CS6 for Mac. They are both dragons and I want the dragons to be the same colour. I have entered the same value however the colours are different. I noticed that the CMYK spectrum for both documents are different - one appears to be lighter than the other. How do I change this so they are both the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like both documents have different colour profiles or are using different colour spaces. Some things to check:

- Ensure File → Document Color Mode is CMYK for both.
- Ensure Edit → Assign Profile is using the same profile for both.
- Ensure View → Proof Setup and Proof Colors are the same for both.

It should be one of those things.